# c# .Net WebApi - Receive parametes from POST and Uri

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

Just a simple question:

Is is possible to extend this webapi method in order to receive json paylod as now and a parameter from uri ?

This is the code:

```
    [Authorize]
    [Route("save")]
    public IHttpActionResult api_Offert_SAVE(reqOffertSave req)
```

In this moment the webapi method url is something like this:

```
http://localhost/save
```

I want to add a new parameter in order to be able to call the method in this way:

```
http://localhost/save?log=true
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You can add it to your route and your method signature as a parameter, something like `[Route("save/{log:bool}")]` .. `api_Offert_SAVE(bool log, reqOffertSave req)` -- See more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) for attribute routing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `[FromBody]` and `[FromUri]` for the parameters you want from `json payload` and for the parameters you want from `uri` respectively

```
[Authorize]
[Route("save")]
public IHttpActionResult api_Offert_SAVE([FromBody] reqOffertSave req, [FromUri] bool log) {
   /* rest of your API */
}
```